# How can I convert between related types through a common initializer?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to build up a family of types that can be converted to each other.  For example, Float and Double can be converted to each other through their initializers.  I'd like to not have to create an exhaustive list of initializers showing that each type can convert to every other type.

I tried to do something like this in a Playground, but it crashes:

```
protocol FloatConvertible {
    init(_ x:FloatConvertible)
}

extension FloatConvertible {
    init(_ x:FloatConvertible){self.init(Self(x))}
}

extension Float:FloatConvertible {}
extension Double:FloatConvertible {}

func transmute<T:FloatConvertible, U:FloatConvertible>
    (a:T, b:U) -> T {
    return T(b)
}

transmute(Float(3.1), b: Double(2.6))
```

My eventual goal isn't just to do the conversion, but to multiply `a` by `b` like so:

```
func *<T:FloatConvertible, U:FloatConvertible> (a:T, b:U) -> T{
    return a * T(b)
}
```

So that I can express the multiply.

Is there a way to do this?  I think part of the problem is winding up with a structure that looks like `Double(Double(Double(Double(...)))`, but I don't think I can put a constraint that ensures `T != U`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your `init(_ x:FloatConvertible)`, Swift cannot infer what the concrete type of `x` is. It just knows that it's a `FloatConvertible`. Therefore when you try to do `Self(x)`, while it *can* infer the concrete type of `Self`, it doesn't know which initialiser you want to call, meaning that it will default to your `init(_ x:FloatConvertible)` initialiser, thus creating an infinite loop.

If you give your custom initialiser an argument name, you'll see that Swift complains that it can't find the correct initialiser:

```
protocol FloatConvertible {
    init(c x:FloatConvertible)
}

extension FloatConvertible {
    init(c x:FloatConvertible) {
        // error: missing argument name 'c:' in call
        // (i.e it can't find the concrete type's initialiser)
        self.init(Self(x)) 
    }
}
```

A *potential* solution therefore is to resolve this at runtime by `switch`ing over the concrete types that `x` could be. However this isn't nearly as good as resolving this statically, as you can benefit from increased safety and in some cases increased performance.

In order to do this statically, you could add a generic `_asOther` 'shadow' function to your protocol that can convert a given floating point type to another, as well as adding the concrete type's initialisers to your protocol requirement.

This will save you from having to list out all the possible combinations of conversions – you can now just invoke `_asOther` from your initialiser.

```
protocol FloatConvertible {
    init(_ other:Float)
    init(_ other:Double)
    init(_ other:CGFloat)
    init(fromOther x:FloatConvertible)

    func _asOther<T:FloatConvertible>() -> T
}

extension FloatConvertible {
    init(fromOther x:FloatConvertible) {self = x._asOther()}
}

// note that we have to implement these for each extension,
// so that Swift uses the concrete types of self, preventing an infinite loop
extension Float : FloatConvertible {
    func _asOther<T:FloatConvertible>() -> T {return T(self)}
}

extension Double : FloatConvertible {
    func _asOther<T:FloatConvertible>() -> T {return T(self)}
}

extension CGFloat : FloatConvertible {
    func _asOther<T:FloatConvertible>() -> T {return T(self)}

    // note that CGFloat doesn't implement its own initialiser for this,
    // so we have to implement it ourselves
    init(_ other:CGFloat) {self = other}
}

func transmute<T:FloatConvertible, U:FloatConvertible>(value: T, to: U.Type) -> U {
    return U(fromOther: value)
}

let f = transmute(value: CGFloat(2.6), to: Float.self)
print(type(of: f), f) // prints: Double 2.59999990463257
```

In the initialiser, `_asOther` will be called on the input value, with the type of `self` being inferred for the generic parameter `T` (in this context `self` is guaranteed to be a concrete type). The `_asOther` function will then get called on `x`, which will return the value as the given destination type.

Note that you *don't* have to use the `fromOther:` argument label for your custom initialiser – this will still work without any label. Although I would strongly advocate for using it to catch any problems with your code at compile time (Swift would accept code that would cause infinite loops at runtime otherwise).

---

Also as a side note, you should maybe re-think your design for how you want your `*` overload to work. It would make more sense to be returning the more precise type that you input into it (i.e `Float * Double = Double`) – otherwise you're just needlessly losing precision.

Comment: Took me a bit to think this one through. I didn't realize it was ok to assign to self in a non-failable initializer...  Regarding the multiply overload, the types I'm using are a bit different that `Float` and `Double` (but those made the problem easier to explain).  I'm pretty sure though that the result can only be as precise as the least precise term in the multiplication.  I think a `Double` result would be bigger than the precision of the result would justify.

Comment: @Omegaman Ah okay, if it makes sense for your specific implementation, then that's obviously fine. Being able to assign to `self` in the initialiser is one of the advantages of using structs here (not possible with classes), as it allows us to infer the concrete type of `self` and thus pass it into the generic conversion method. We could of used `self.init` instead of `self =`, but that would have required our custom initialiser to take a parameter label to disambiguate. Happy to help :)