# How to implement generic conversion initializer in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, type-conversion, swift-protocols, swift3

I'm implementing a 2D vector struct in Swift:

```
public struct Vec2<T: Numeric> {
    public let x: T
    public let y: T

    public init(_ x: T, _ y: T) {
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
    }

    // ...
}

public protocol Numeric: Equatable {
    // ...
}

extension Int: Numeric {}
extension Double: Numeric {}
extension Float: Numeric {}
```

This code compiles. Now I would like to add a **conversion initializer** to allow converting e.g. a `Vec2<Int>` to a `Vec2<Float>`. I added this to `Vec2`:

```
    public init<T2: Numeric>(_ other: Vec2<T2>) {
        self.x = T(other.x)
        self.y = T(other.y)
    }
```

and the needed initializers to the `Numeric` protocol:

```
    init(_: Int)
    init(_: Double)
    init(_: Float)
```

However, this causes an error that I'm unable to solve:

> cannot invoke initializer for type 'T' with an argument list of type '(T2)'
>
> overloads for 'T' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Int), (Double), (Float)

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem (slightly different to the dupe question, but I'm not sure it warrants a separate answer) is that your protocol cannot guarantee that every concrete type that conforms to `Numeric` is handled by the initialisers you list in the requirements. You therefore have to do something like adding a 'shadow' function requirement to the protocol to guarantee that every type implements its own conversion logic – which I detail in my answer to the above linked question.

Comment: @originaluser2 Thanks, that solved it!

Comment: @Hamish Is there a generic FloatingPoint initializer that takes a StringProtocol type?

Answer (score 1):

The `_asOther` 'shadow' function solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37566026/3425536) worked. Just in case anyone's interested, here's the final code:

```
public struct Vec2<T: Numeric> {
    public let x: T
    public let y: T

    public init(_ x: T, _ y: T) {
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
    }

    public init<T2: Numeric>(_ other: Vec2<T2>) {
        self.x = other.x._asOther()
        self.y = other.y._asOther()
    }

    // ...
}

public protocol Numeric: Equatable {
    init(_: Int)
    init(_: Double)
    init(_: Float)
    func _asOther<T: Numeric>() -> T
    // ...
}

extension Int: Numeric {
    public func _asOther<T: Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }
}

extension Double: Numeric {
    public func _asOther<T: Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }
}

extension Float: Numeric {
    public func _asOther<T: Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }
}
```

Comment: You cannot type cast with `T`.

Comment: Also, `Int`, `Double`, and `Float` already conform to the `Numeric` protocol and as such are redundant.

Comment: Yeah, haven't tried this with newer Swift versions. This used to work in Swift 2 IIRC when there wasn't `Numeric` in the stdlib.