# How to cast generic number type 'T' to CGFloat

Tags: swift, generics, type-conversion

I have a class that accepts numeric types through generic T type, I wanted to be able to convert it to the `CGFloat` but it throws:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(T)'

What I have to do in my class to be able to convert it successfully?

`CGFloat(self.top)` - this is what it didnt like

The 'T' type is defined as follows:

```
protocol Numeric:Comparable, Equatable {
    //
    init(_ v:Float)
    init(_ v:Double)
    init(_ v:Int)
    init(_ v:UInt)
    init(_ v:Int8)
    init(_ v:UInt8)
    init(_ v:Int16)
    init(_ v:UInt16)
    init(_ v:Int32)
    init(_ v:UInt32)
    init(_ v:Int64)
    init(_ v:UInt64)
}
extension Float: Numeric {}
extension Double: Numeric {}
extension Int: Numeric {}
extension Int8: Numeric {}
extension Int16: Numeric {}
extension Int32: Numeric {}
extension Int64: Numeric {}
extension UInt: Numeric {}
extension UInt8: Numeric {}
extension UInt16: Numeric {}
extension UInt32: Numeric {}
extension UInt64: Numeric {}

class MyClass<T: Numeric> {
//...
    var top:T
}
```

When I tried with `as` then this runtime error popped up

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Double' (0x1002b64f8) to
>   'CoreGraphics.CGFloat' (0x1004e8740).

Comment: Related: [How can I convert between related types through a common initializer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556276/how-can-i-convert-between-related-types-through-a-common-initializer). You could resolve your problem statically through adding a 'shadow method' to your protocol requirement such as `_asOther() -> T`, allowing each type that conforms to the protocol to convert themselves to another type.

Comment: Could you show the implementation based on my example? I would be happy to accept this answer if it is cleaner/shorter etc.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you'd consider it cleaner or shorter, but there are benefits in doing it the way I've suggested, which I've explained in my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an extension [to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37566026/2976878), you could achieve this statically through using a 'shadow method' in order to allow `Numeric` types to coerce themselves to any other `Numeric` type (given that the initialiser for the destination type is listed as a protocol requirement).

For example, you could define your `Numeric` protocol like so:

```
protocol Numeric : Comparable, Equatable {

    init(_ v:Float)
    init(_ v:Double)
    init(_ v:Int)
    init(_ v:UInt)
    init(_ v:Int8)
    init(_ v:UInt8)
    init(_ v:Int16)
    init(_ v:UInt16)
    init(_ v:Int32)
    init(_ v:UInt32)
    init(_ v:Int64)
    init(_ v:UInt64)
    init(_ v:CGFloat)

    // 'shadow method' that allows instances of Numeric
    // to coerce themselves to another Numeric type
    func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T
}

extension Numeric {

    // Default implementation of init(fromNumeric:) simply gets the inputted value
    // to coerce itself to the same type as the initialiser is called on
    // (the generic parameter T in _asOther() is inferred to be the same type as self)
    init<T:Numeric>(fromNumeric numeric: T) { self = numeric._asOther() }
}
```

And then conform types to `Numeric` like so:

```
// Implementations of _asOther() – they simply call the given initialisers listed
// in the protocol requirement (it's required for them to be repeated like this,
// as the compiler won't know which initialiser you're referring to otherwise)
extension Float   : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension Double  : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension CGFloat : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension Int     : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension Int8    : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension Int16   : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension Int32   : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension Int64   : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension UInt    : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension UInt8   : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension UInt16  : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension UInt32  : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
extension UInt64  : Numeric {func _asOther<T:Numeric>() -> T { return T(self) }}
```

Example usage:

```
class MyClass<T : Numeric> {

    var top : T

    init(_ top:T) {
        self.top = top
    }

    func topAsCGFloat() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(fromNumeric: top)
    }
}

let m = MyClass(Int32(42))
let converted = m.topAsCGFloat()

print(type(of:converted), converted) // prints: CGFloat 42.0
```

This solution is probably no shorter than implementing a method that switches through every type that conforms to `Numeric` – however as this solution doesn't rely on runtime type-casting, the compiler will likely have more opportunities for optimisation.

It also benefits from static type-checking, meaning that you cannot conform a new type to `Numeric` without also implementing the logic to convert that type to another type of `Numeric` (in your case, you would crash at runtime if the type wasn't handled in the `switch`).

Furthermore, because of encapsulation, it's more flexible to expand, as the logic to convert types is done in each individual concrete type that conforms to `Numeric`, rather than a single method that handles the possible cases.

Comment: I had just tested this and found that CGFloat will throw an error that it is not conformant to Numeric protocol, for this you need: `extension CGFloat{
    public  init(_ value: CGFloat){
        self = value
    }
}`

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela In Swift 3, `CGFloat` already has a [`public init(_ value: CGFloat)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgfloat/1845223-init). Are you using Swift 2?

Answer (score 2):

Solution was within the grasp of my hand:) first look at this link:

[Richard Fox - Cast-Free Arithmetic in Swift](https://realm.io/news/richard-fox-casting-swift-2/)

Then it was as simple as adding following to my existing code:

```
protocol Numeric:Comparable, Equatable {
    //
    init(_ v:Float)
    init(_ v:Double)
    init(_ v:Int)
    init(_ v:UInt)
    init(_ v:Int8)
    init(_ v:UInt8)
    init(_ v:Int16)
    init(_ v:UInt16)
    init(_ v:Int32)
    init(_ v:UInt32)
    init(_ v:Int64)
    init(_ v:UInt64)
    init(_ value: CGFloat)
}
extension Numeric {

    func convert<T: Numeric>() -> T {
        switch self {
        case let x as CGFloat:
            return T(x) //T.init(x)
        case let x as Float:
            return T(x)
        case let x as Double:
            return T(x)
        case let x as Int:
            return T(x)
        case let x as UInt:
            return T(x)
        case let x as Int8:
            return T(x)
        case let x as UInt8:
            return T(x)
        case let x as Int16:
            return T(x)
        case let x as UInt16:
            return T(x)
        case let x as Int32:
            return T(x)
        case let x as UInt32:
            return T(x)
        case let x as Int64:
            return T(x)
        case let x as UInt64:
            return T(x)
        default:
            assert(false, "Numeric convert cast failed!")
            return T(0)
        }
    }
}

extension CGFloat{
    public  init(_ value: CGFloat){
        self = value
    }
}
```

And then use it as follows: `let c:CGFloat = self.top.convert()`