# Generic with default value of nil

Tags: swift, generics

I'm attempting to create a generic class/struct initializer that converts any value it takes in and assigns it to its Double properties. (Note: the as! or as? pattern below is just being used to save space here. I'm actually using [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486362/how-to-cast-generic-number-type-t-to-cgfloat) to convert my values.)

The idea here is that I'd like to be able to mix Integers, Doubles, CGFloats, etc (i.e. anything in the Numeric generic type constraint) and have them all end up as Doubles. It works in other situations, but I'm running into an issue here.

In the pared down example below I'm creating a Vector class and the `z` property should be able to be nil in case we're only dealing with 2 dimensions.

```
struct Vector {
    
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    var z: Double?
    
    public init<X: Numeric, Y: Numeric, Z: Numeric>(_ x: X, _ y: Y, _ z: Z? = nil){
        self.x = x as! Double
        self.y = y as! Double
        self.z = z as? Double
    }
}

var myVector = Vector(4, 3.4)

print("""
    \(myVector.x)
    \(myVector.y)
    \(myVector.z)
    """
)
```

The problem is that I get an error that says `Generic parameter 'Z' could not be inferred`.

Comment: Note that Swift has a native Numeric Protocol since Swift 4. You should choose another name to represent your protocol. Something like DoubleConvertible

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyxou894og3di26/Vector%20Playground.playground.zip?dl=1

Comment: I find the premise here a little suspicious. How frequently are you running into pairs/triplets of numbers of mismatched types that you need to handle this way?

Comment: Fair question. In our particular use case (education and graphics), users will say, for example color(0,0,125.6). The 125.6 could be fed in by a random(255) function that returns Doubles. To a new programmer the distinction between an Integer and a Double is not clear. The additional complication is that we are interfacing with Core Graphics, which uses CGFloats and not Doubles. If a user creates a variable with type inference, a floating point will always be inferred as a Double. Pass that into a function that expects CGFloats and you have an error. This has affected our API a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with two separate intitializers, one of which doesn't need to have an unused generic `Z`:

```
struct Vector {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
    var z: Double?
}

extension Vector {
    public init<X: Numeric, Y: Numeric>(_ x: X, _ y: Y) {
        self.init(x: x as! Double, y: y as! Double, z: nil as Double?)
    }
    
    public init<X: Numeric, Y: Numeric, Z: Numeric>(_ x: X, _ y: Y, _ z: Z? = nil) {
        self.init(x: x as! Double, y: y as! Double, z: z as? Double)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error when I try to execute this in playground -"Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Int' (0x7fff8182dce0) to 'Swift.Double' (0x7fff8182d9e8)."  @Alexander

Comment: @Bharad See OP's note: "(Note: the as! or as? pattern below is just being used to save space here. I'm actually using [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486362/how-to-cast-generic-number-type-t-to-cgfloat) to convert my values.)"