# Extension of Array of FloatingPoint Elements in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, floating-point, swift3, swift-extensions

How can I compactly write an extension of an `Array` in Swift 3.0 which works for both `Float` and `Double` `Element` types?

The following doesn't work:

```
extension Array where Element: FloatingPoint
{
    public func multiply(mult: Double) -> [Double] {
        return self.map{Double($0) * mult}
    }
}
```

With the error being

> Unable to infer closure type in the current context

Why can't the closure type be inferred? Is this a current limitation of the compiler, or is there a good reason why the closure type can't be inferred?

A more explicit version doesn't work either:

```
extension Array where Element: FloatingPoint
{
    public func multiply(mult: Double) -> [Double] {
        return self.map{(x: Element) -> Double in Double(v: x) * mult}
    }
}
```

With the error this time being

> Ambiguous reference to member '*'

Where again I'm not sure of the reason for this error.

Comment: @Hamish Doing what you suggest works, thanks! That might be good enough. However, what if I indeed want to return an array of `Double`? (For example, consider a case where instead of controlling the type of `mult` parameter, as in the example above, I instead have no parameters, but instead multiply by a function which I didn't write which returns `Double`. In that case to multiply the `Array` elements by that function they need to be converted to `Double` and a `[Double]` should be returned.

Comment: I went ahead and converted my comments to an answer :)

Comment: @Hamish you might be interested at  DoubleConvertible implementation with Initializer as suggested by Martin R here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794282/how-do-i-make-my-operator-work-with-double-and-int which I used here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29179878/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah, it's quite a common solution to the problem of "a type which you can pass into a given overload of a function" (in this case `Double`'s `init(_:)`). You can actually generalise it too in order to work with conversions between different types, see for example [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37566026/2976878).

Comment: Yes and Swift 3 even allows  Protocol Composition so you can specify more than one protocol (check Swift 3 book page 576/577) and allow you to pass an object of any type if it has the required properties.

Comment: @LeoDabus Swift 2 also had protocol composition ;) It just had different syntax (`protocol<X, Y, Z>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically, your extension should work by multiplying an array of homogenous floating-point types with a value of the same type, and returning an array of that type. You can simply express this with an argument of type `Element`, and a return of `[Element]`:

```
// this could also just be an extension of Sequence
extension Array where Element : FloatingPoint {

    public func multiply(by factor: Element) -> [Element] {
        return self.map { $0 * factor }
    }
}
```

Therefore for a `[Float]`, this would accept an argument of type `Float` and return a `[Float]`.

> However, what if I indeed want to return an array of `Double`?

I do not *believe* it's possible to construct a `Double` from an arbitrary `FloatingPoint` (or even `BinaryFloatingPoint`) conforming instance, as neither protocol (although they do require implementation of various aspects of the IEEE 754 specification) actually defines the precise encoding of the conforming type.

However, if you *really* want this, you could just write two overloads – one for `Float` elements and one for `Double` elements:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Float {

    public func multiply(by factor: Double) -> [Double] {
        return self.map { Double($0) * factor }
    }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Double {

    public func multiply(by factor: Double) -> [Double] {
        return self.map { $0 * factor }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you plan on making this work with a broader range of types, you can use a `protocol` in order to define a requirement that allows conforming types to express their value as a `Double`:

```
protocol ConvertibleToDouble {
    func _asDouble() -> Double
}

extension Float : ConvertibleToDouble {
    func _asDouble() -> Double { return Double(self) }
}

extension Double : ConvertibleToDouble {
    func _asDouble() -> Double { return self }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : ConvertibleToDouble {

    func multiply(by factor: Double) -> [Double] {
        return self.map { $0._asDouble() * factor }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to let it be as an answer :)

Comment: Doesn't Swift already have a `ConvertibleToDouble` protocol or similar?

Comment: @Danra Not that I'm aware of (feel free to prove me wrong :) )